# Hash, salt and best practices

Tags: hash, salt, client-side

Reading about hashing, salt and pepper, I can't get my head around the following scenario:

If there's a web application and you register on that site, should the password be hashed on the client or server-side? If you would consider hashing it on the client-side, you also have to generate an individual salt that then is appended to your password and that combination gets hashed and then send to the server along with the salt **or** you could also hash the password, send that to the server and the salt gets then appended to the hash by the server, which is then again hashed. But if an attacker is able to intercept the connection between client and server during login, he's not interested in the salt, because the client just sends the hashed (or cleartext) password to the server... And if the attacker is able to break into the database, he's still able to bruteforce the hash. So as far as my knowledge goes, salts are only useful against RainbowTable attacks(?)

What's the best practice then? Who should hash the password and where should the salt be appended?

Comment: [Client-side hashing of a password is uncommon](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/53594/118310) [because people use SSL instead](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/143857/118310) so encrypted password is sent to server and everything then happens at server side: **Hash[hash(password) ⊕ Salt]**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Client side password hashing](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23006/client-side-password-hashing), [https security - should password be hashed server-side or client-side?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/145637/), [Can client-side hashing improve after-the-fact security in response to password leaks?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/95004/) and many more.

Comment: Not a duplicate as salts are involved. Answer has already been provided by cegfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking salts and hashes are done server-side, not client side. The communication between server and client should be protected with encryption (TLS).  As Anders mentions in a comment this may answer a lot of your questions: [For an HTTPS web application, is it worthwhile to encrypt the password before POSTing it, to keep a MITM attacker from harversting it?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/66475/for-an-https-web-application-is-it-worthwhile-to-encrypt-the-password-before-po)

About salts and hashing in general: the idea behind salts and hashes often boils down to forcing the attacker to perform a brute-force algorithm.  This both (a) buys the service time to secure the network and change user passwords, and (b) prevents bad actors inside the company/website from acquiring the user's password (for naughty things like trying that password on other sites).

Salts do many things. (1) protects against rainbow table attacks like you said, (2) in the case of data breach, it makes password-cracking more difficult than vanilla hash (that is, there's no way an attacker can build a database of all hashes for an algorithm; they'd have to have that database for *every* hash, which is not feasible); this buys the site/users time to change the algorithm and passwords, (3) prevents people working for the site to be able to easily steal a user's password, and (4) grants more architectural options for securing the authentication process.

To talk about (4) for a minute, a (very large international) client of mine had a microservice architecture, and their authentication processes worked by hashing the password with one of many salts (based on username) *before*  sending it to the microservice which checked the actual database.  This type of separation prevented the code handling the database to know both salt and password, and the microservice which knew the salt would not keep hashes (neither in-memory nor on-disk). An attacker could not use a database dump; they'd need database *and* software from *more than one* server.  This increases complexity, as a stolen database gets them no closer to hashing the database; they'd also need the list of salts (from another server).  No employee had access to both servers, which helped with (3).

**Why hashing client-side isn't super useful**:
A man in the middle attack can capture whatever is transmitted between the client and the server.  Hashing the password before sending does very little; the attacker doesn't have to be able to *generate* the hash, they'd just have to send the exact same request again to get access.

For example, let's look the following requests and parameters (I'm not using real HTTP headers for readability):

```
POST /auth/login
user=me@example.com
pass=mypassword
```

versus:

```
POST /auth/login
user=me@example.com
pass=89e01536ac207279409d4de1e5253e01f4a1769e696db0d6062ca9b8f56767c8
```

The server can't know by the hash that the real password is "mypassword", so it'll just use the hash as-is to verify the user's account.  An attacker who can read that request doesn't need to know that your password is "mypassword", they just need to take the hash; that gives no protection for the account. The *only* thing this prevents is the attacker being able to test the password on other sites (eg, many people foolishly use the same email and password for google and their bank).